# Ruby: Rename First Key of Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
[
    [0] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    [1] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    [2] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    [3] {
        "Success" => true
    }
]
```

Each number above has a much larger multidimensional array associated with it, but that is not my concern currently. I am wanting to rename the numbers [0..3] with new key values.

So it would look like this

```
[
    ["pop"] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    ["rock"] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    ["country"] {
        "Success" => true
    },
    ["soul/r&b"] {
        "Success" => true
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea how to do it in Ruby, but your "Array" is actually a JSON object, so it might help if you search for help renaming JSON values in Ruby.

Comment: **your input is not a Ruby Array!** did you post the wrong input, or are you trying to modify a JSON object?

Comment: Sorry. The output is a JSON object. My explanation was off. I was trying to rename the JSON Object keys

Comment: My apologies here for the disregard for the horrible explanation of what I was trying to accomplish, or at least for giving a malformed Array. I wrote this post really quick in hopes of a quick answer, as I was working with several other projects at once. I am extremely grateful for the help that was given and I will make sure to form my questions 100% before submitting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your input is really JSON, you need to first parse the JSON and convert it into a Ruby data structure:

```
require 'active_support'

json = "[[0,{\"Success\":true}],[1,{\"Success\":true}],[2,{\"Success\":true}],[3,{\"Success\":true}]]"

array = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode( json )
 => [ [0, { "Success" => true }], [1, { "Success" => true }], [2, { "Success" => true }], [3, { "Success" => true }] ]
```

Now your input is a Ruby Array...

I assume you have the new keys stored in an array somewhere like this:

```
new_keys = %w{pop rock country soul/r&b}
 => ["pop", "rock", "country", "soul/r&b"]
```

Next step is to replace the first element of each of the sub-arrays in the JSON array with the new key:

```
result = Array.new
array.each do |value|
   i, rest = value
   result << [ new_keys[i], rest ]
end

json = result.to_json

  => "[[\"pop\",{\"Success\":true}],
       [\"rock\",{\"Success\":true}],
       [\"country\",{\"Success\":true}],
       [\"soul/r&b\",{\"Success\":true}]]"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two array like data structures in Ruby: the array which stores ordered data accessible by an integer index and the hash, which is a hashmap storing data accessible by some key object (e.g. a string). Although they are both accessed similarly, they are different classes.

From your code (which is not valid ruby btw.) I'm guessing you have the following data structure:

```
array = [
  { "Success" => true },
  { "Success" => true },
  { "Success" => true },
  { "Success" => true }
]
```

It can be transferred usiong the following code:

```
keys = ["pop", "rock", "country", "soul/r&b"]
result = {}
keys.each_with_index {|key, i| result[index] = array[i]}
```

This results in the following data structure. It is a hash containing the elements of the original array (which are hashes by themselves) as values.

```
{
  "pop" =>      { "Success" => true },
  "rock" =>     { "Success" => true },
  "country" =>  { "Success" => true },
  "soul/r&b" => { "Success" => true }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I was able to use what you and @Tilo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
styles = {0: "pop", 1: "rock", 2: "country", 3: "shoul/r&b"}
info2 = Hash[info.map { |index, h| [[styles[index]], h}]
```

Comment: unfortunately the input is not a Hash

Comment: @UnixGuy: well, we must assume, the OP says "array" while he shows something that does look like a mixture of an array and a hash. Anyway, it's trivial to change this to any input/output type.